# How to insert many to Cosmos DB by ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, insert, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert

Is there any way specialty for insert +1 million records in Cosmos Db with ASP.NET core by fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent method is to use bulk support in the .NET SDK v3. A full tutorial is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-sql-api-dotnet-bulk-import

You'll want to at least temporarily increase the throughput on the database to allow for your desired ingestion speed.

Comment: This way is inserting data as list of tasks that each task is a normal insert. This way don't have difference between itself and many normal insert. In terms of performance is absolutely same.

Comment: I believe the difference is the inserts are done in bulk batches which should saturate available throughput. If you have actually tried it and it doesn't do that, you can always contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB SDK  allows bulk insert with the bulk [**`executor`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net)  via the AllowBulkExecution option with the Dotnet library

```
// Set retry options high during initialization (default values).
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30;
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 9;

IBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = new BulkExecutor(client, dataCollection);
await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync();

// Set retries to 0 to pass complete control to bulk executor.
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 0;
client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 0;
```

Comment: Only on .net framework and not .net core